# Why do I get the NameError error even using self?

Tags: python

Ive always coded in C++ but this time I have to do it in Python.
I understood mostly of what I was doing but this error surpass me.

I undesrtand that it has to do with the "self" in the funnctions, but still using it I still get the error when calling test block()

I would be so grateful for any kind of help.
Thanks.

This is my coding without using "self":

```
import hashlib

class Block():
  def __init__(self, height = 0, timestamp = "", tx = "", nonce = 0, prev_blockhash = "", curr_blockhash = ""):
    self.height = height
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.tx = tx
    self.nonce = nonce
    self.prev_blockhash = prev_blockhash
    self.curr_blockhash = self.hash_blockhash()
  def hash_black(self):
    returning = hashlib.sha256()

    neoHeight = str(self.height)
    neoTimestamp = str(self.timestamp)
    neoTx = str(self.tx)
    neoNonce = str(self.nonce)
    neoPrev_blockhash = str(self.prev_blockhash)

    all = (neoHeight + neoTimestamp + neoTx + neoNonce + neoPrev_blockhash)

    print(all)
    all = all.encode()
    print(all)

    returning.update(all)
    hashed = returning.hexdigest

    return hashed
  def testBlock(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash):
    blockHash = Block(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash)
    blockHashed = blockHash.hash_block()

    print('Block Hashed:')
    print()
    print(blockHashed)
    return blockHashed

height = 0
timestamp = '2021-02-25 11:59:59.134365'
tx = 'Alice, Bob, 10'
nonce = 0
prev_blockhash = hashlib.sha256()
prev_blockhash.update(b'0')


hash = "e2169844b4dbb8a35b15c5da2cd1cccbeb873da319bf5f3983b15b5fb76bafa7"

assert testBlock(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash)
        import hashlib
```

And this using "self"

```
class Block():
  def __init__(self, height = 0, timestamp = "", tx = "", nonce = 0, prev_blockhash = "", curr_blockhash = ""):
    self.height = height
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.tx = tx
    self.nonce = nonce
    self.prev_blockhash = prev_blockhash
    self.curr_blockhash = self.hash_blockhash()
  def hash_black(self):
    returning = hashlib.sha256()

    neoHeight = str(self.height)
    neoTimestamp = str(self.timestamp)
    neoTx = str(self.tx)
    neoNonce = str(self.nonce)
    neoPrev_blockhash = str(self.prev_blockhash)

    all = (neoHeight + neoTimestamp + neoTx + neoNonce + neoPrev_blockhash)

    print(all)
    all = all.encode()
    print(all)

    returning.update(all)
    hashed = returning.hexdigest

    return hashed
  def testBlock(self, height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash):
    blockHash = Block(self.height, self.timestamp, self.tx, self.nonce, self.prev_blockhash)
    blockHashed = blockHash.hash_block()

    print('Block Hashed:')
    print()
    print(blockHashed)
    return blockHashed

height = 0
timestamp = '2021-02-25 11:59:59.134365'
tx = 'Alice, Bob, 10'
nonce = 0
prev_blockhash = hashlib.sha256()
prev_blockhash.update(b'0')

hash = "e2169844b4dbb8a35b15c5da2cd1cccbeb873da319bf5f3983b15b5fb76bafa7"

assert testBlock(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash)
```

In both cases I receive the "NameError" error.

Comment: Please show your full traceback

Comment: If your test block function isn't part of the class, don't indent it as part of the class , and don't include a self parameter

Answer (score 0):

You defined `testBlock` *inside* the `Block` class, which makes it a method on instances of `Block`. You never constructed a `Block` to call `testBlock` on.

It looks like `testBlock` is not intended to be a method of `Block` instances (it creates one itself and tests it), so take the original code (without `self` on `testBlock`), and dedent the definition of `testBlock` so it's not part of the `Block` class, then things should work (assuming no other errors elsewhere in the code).

Comment: The assert statement needs to be asserting something as well

Comment: @OneCricketeer: It is asserting something; that the return value from `testBlock` is truthy. Not sure what that means in this context aside from "yep, got a hash back" (and tracing further, I see a method is named `hashBlack` but invoked as `hashBlock` so that needs fixing), but it is asserting something, just a pretty useless sort of assertion.

Comment: Right, but seems like it should be using `== hash` at the end

Comment: Thanks for the advice, now, just like in C++, I called the method testblock with a Block object. Now im getting this error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    example = Block(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash)
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.curr_blockhash = self.hash_blockhash()
AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'hash_blockhash'

Comment: Ive corrected some minor errors ans still get an error.

Comment: height = 0
timestamp = '2021-02-25 11:59:59.134365'
tx = 'Alice, Bob, 10'
nonce = 0
prev_blockhash = hashlib.sha256()
prev_blockhash.update(b'0')
curr_blockhash = hashlib.sha256()
curr_blockhash.update(b'0')

example = Block(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash, curr_blockhash)
hash = "e2169844b4dbb8a35b15c5da2cd1cccbeb873da319bf5f3983b15b5fb76bafa7"

assert example.testBlock(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash, curr_blockhash)

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    example = Block(height, timestamp, tx, nonce, prev_blockhash, curr_blockhash)
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.curr_blockhash = self.curr_blockhash()
AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'curr_blockhash'


Comment: @user16919308: These are all *really* obvious self-explanatory errors; the error says *exactly* what the problem is, and if you understood Python classes and objects even a tiny bit, you should be able to figure out why it's a problem. The lines don't even make sense as is, which makes me suspect your blindly rewriting code you don't understand in the first place. I feel like you need to go back to your teacher or a Python tutorial and run through it from the beginning; if the cause of simple `AttributeError`s isn't obvious, you've got critical gaps in understanding all over.